# "__built-in-schema.yml (Line: 2012, Col: 24): Expected a mapping" after V2-V3 pipeline converstion

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

UPDATE: Here's the contents of azure_pipelines.yml:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: pf
    type: git
    name: _
    ref: refs/tags/3.6.6
trigger: none

stages:
- template: __
  parameters:
    project:
    - name: "__" # Must be unique within the list of projects
      type: "msbuild" # Used with Publish/Deploy.  Options: adla, dacpac, dotnet, egg, maven, msbuild, node, nuget, python, sap, ssis
      path: "__" # Project Path
      file: "__.csproj" # Project file
      toolset: "msbuild" # Used with Build/Package.  Options: adla, dotnet, maven, msbuild, node, python, sap, ssis
      playbook: "___.yml"
      sonarqube:
        name: scan
        scan: true
        sqExclusions: ""
        additionalProperties: "" #|
#            sonar.branch.name=master
#            sonar.branch.target=master
      fortify: 
        fortifyApp: "_______" 
        fortifyVersion: "____"
        sast: true
        dast: false
      buildConfiguration: $(BuildConfiguration) #release, debug
      buildPlatform: $(BuildPlatform) #any cpu, x86, x64
    - name: "__" # Must be unique within the list of projects
      type: "msbuild" # Used with Publish/Deploy.  Options: adla, dacpac, dotnet, egg, maven, msbuild, node, nuget, python, sap, ssis
      path: "___" # Project Path
      file: "___.csproj" # Project file
      toolset: "msbuild" # Used with Build/Package.  Options: adla, dotnet, maven, msbuild, node, python, sap, ssis
      playbook: "_.yml"
      sonarqube:
        name: scan
        scan: true
        sqExclusions: ""
        additionalProperties: "" #|
#            sonar.branch.name=master
#            sonar.branch.target=master
      fortify: 
        fortifyApp: "______" 
        fortifyVersion: "__"
        sast: true
        dast: false
      buildConfiguration: $(BuildConfiguration) #release, debug
      buildPlatform: $(BuildPlatform) #any cpu, x86, x64
```

I'm attempting to run the ADO pipeline for a .NET Framework 4.7 app that has undergone the V2 to V3 pipeline conversion. I get the following error message, and the build doesn't even try to run:

```
__built-in-schema.yml: Maximum object depth exceeded
__built-in-schema.yml (Line: 2012, Col: 24): Expected a mapping
__built-in-schema.yml: Maximum object depth exceeded
```

That's using the msbuild toolset. I have an API project and a web app project in the solution, so if I removed either of them and then run the pipeline, it progresses past this stage, but gets hung on another error. (Not really necessary to go into detail about that error though, because it's directly related to me having removed the other project).

With the dotnet toolset, it runs, but then complains about a missing reference:

```
> D:\a\1\s\___\___.csproj(350,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
    0 Warning(s)
```

I've tried commenting out the reference to Microsoft.WebApplication.targets in the .csproj files for the app, but it just adds them back in when I run the build locally or via the pipeline.

I've also tried changing the build pool to VS 2017 and Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019, thinking the VS targets would be available in those pools, but no luck.

I also tried installing MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets via NuGet, but end up with the same results.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide more clarity on the file path depth? I've added the contents of my azure-pipelines.yml file to see if that helps.

Comment: It is more related to the path in your repos, You could try to set it in the repo without deep path.

Comment: Ah that's the rub - I don't control the repo for the code being called here. They're Ansible roles being pulled in via the pipeline at build time. I'll have to attack this from another angle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “__built-in-schema.yml (Line: 2012, Col: 24): Expected a mapping” after V2-V3 pipeline converstion

According to the error log:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
>   was not found

We could to know the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` invoked from dotnet SDK instead of MSBuild. The correct path for `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` should be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
```

So, we need use MSBuild toolset instead of the dotnet toolset. And since it use the MSBuild 16.0, we need use the build agent pool Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019 to build the project.

For the error `Maximum object depth exceeded`, it seems your yaml file has too deep file path, please try to shortening the file path to see if this resolves the issue.

If above info not help you, please share more info about you issue, like what is your project type, is python project? And share your build pipeline (yaml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same issue and it feels like this is connected to the depth of the templates. Since I see this issue when I'm adding a template usage, but then when I'm moving the internal template out of that template - the issue goes away

Comment: @MarkiyanHarbych, Yes, some of other users have also reacted to this problem because the depth of the yaml file.

Comment: So do you know what is the actual limit? cannot find it in the documentation. It would be a lot easier to avoid it while knowing it

Comment: @MarkiyanHarbych, I also did not find related documents.